# numpy.dot returning the same value as one of the vectors

Tags: python, numpy, dictionary, dot-product

I have a dictionary with key, value pairs as `{'p h' : 12, 'i e' : 14}`, with a biphone and its frequency in the text corpus.

```
    biphone_frequency = get_biphone_dist(baseline_corpus_phonetic)
```

This function returns a dictionary with the above specifications from a text corpus.

I need to create two dictionaries such that one `uniform_RP` represents the uniform percentage distribution of all the biphones, and the other `correlation_CP` displays the **actual** percentage distribution of biphones. So, I take:

```
    length_dict = len(biphone_frequency.values())
    sum_dict = sum(biphone_frequency.values())

    #calculating uniform distribution of all the biphones
    rp = 1.0/float(length_dict)

    # creating dictionary with constant values wrt every biphone
    uniform_RP = {x : rp for x in biphone_frequency.keys()}         

    # creating dictionary with actual values wrt every biphone
      correlation_CP = {}
      for key, val in biphone_frequency.items():
          cp = val/float(sum_dict)   ##individual %age distribution
          correlation_CP[key] = cp
```

I need to find the dot product between `correlation_CP.values()` and `uniform_RP.values()`. So I use:

```
      RP_values = np.array(uniform_RP.values())
      CP_values = np.array(correlation_CP.values())
      correlation_coefficient = np.dot(RP_values, CP_values)
```

The problem is that the dot product is always the same as the value in `uniform_RP.values()`. Can anyone suggest why this could be happening?!

Comment: BTW, `correlation_CP = {k: v / sum_dict for k, v in biphone_frequency.items()}`. Don't forget to make `sum_dict` into a ` float` before the dictionary comprehension.

Comment: Also, you should clarify that it's the mean value that you're referring to in the last sentence.

Comment: It looks like you are starting to develop a habit of not selecting answers OP. If someone answers your question to your satisfaction, you should click on the check mark next to the answer.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because that's how dot product is defined. You are multiplying each element by 1/N, then adding them up. This is because `uniform_RP` contains 1/N for every value. The result will always be the mean of `correlation_CP`.

I am using 1/N instead of `1.0/length_dict` for empasis. They mean the same thing.